# ios iAds not hiding correctly

Tags: ios, iad

I am using this code to hide iAd as apple documentation recommends. but sometimes it does not hide iAd, even the logging suggests inner code of if-block runs.

```
-(void)bannerView:(ADBannerView *)banner didFailToReceiveAdWithError:(NSError *)error
{
    NSLog(@"Error loading");

    if (isAdVisible == YES )
    {
        NSLog(@"Inside error loading");
        [UIView beginAnimations:@"animateAdBannerOff" context:NULL];
        banner.frame = CGRectMake(0, -50, 320, 50);
        [UIView commitAnimations];
        isAdVisible = NO;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I use `CGRectOffset` to offset the banner.frame (it returns a rectangle with an origin that is offset from that of the source rectangle). Then I launch the animation with a block.The following code, called inside `bannerView:didFailToReceiveAdWithError:`, resizes my `UITabBarController.tabBar` and hides the `AdBannerView` below it:

```
-(void) hideBanner: (UIView*) banner
{
    NSLog(@"Running %@ '%@'", self.class, NSStringFromSelector(_cmd));

    // Hide the banner by sliding down while resizing the contentController.view.frame
    if(banner && !banner.isHidden){

        CGRect tabBarFrame = self.contentController.tabBar.frame;

        [UIView animateWithDuration:0.25 animations:^{

            self.contentController.tabBar.frame = CGRectOffset(tabBarFrame, 0, banner.frame.size.height);
            banner.frame = CGRectOffset(banner.frame, 0, banner.frame.size.height);

        } completion:^(BOOL finished) {
            banner.hidden = YES;
        }];
    }
}
```